# estimating amount of logic gates in FPGA for VHDL code

Tags: vhdl, fpga, synthesis

I've written a VHDL code for an assignment, and now I'm trying to figure out what it the cheapest FPGA I can buy that could run this code. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Install the development tools for each FPGA vendor and run your design through it. Try different devices till you have found the smallest (which might be the cheapest) . Then go to a big electronic parts website and find the price of each. Find the price of the dev tools and programmers and divide that through the amount of FPGAs you are going to produce. Add that to your device cost, then select the cheapest. Note that this only makes commercial sense if you are going to make a few hundred thousand/million. Otherwise don't bother.

Comment: I just need 1 for a school assignment

Comment: You can shorten the above by going for one vendor and forgetting about the development tools. But you still have to run your VHDL through the vendors synthesis tool and see how many LUTs/registers you need.

Comment: Do you actually want to buy an FPGA or just want to show the research and conclude which FPGA to be used? If you want to buy an FPGA for just one assignment, It's better to look at the available development boards and see which one fits you.